# Check my solution on a card flipping game

Tags: probability, puzzle

I'm trying to solve puzzle. Can someone please check my solution? Thank you!

I have four cards with values $1,2,3,4$ faced down. Each turn, I can either flip a card or do nothing. If I flip a card, I get the face value. If I don't, I get $2.5$. I have four turns. What's the optimal strategy (assuming you're risk neutral) and what is its expected value?

This is my solution. Let $V(a,b,c,d)$ denote the value at each state. The arguments of $V$ can only take zero or one, indicating whether a card is unflipped. For example, $V(1,0,0,0)$ is the value where the card with value $1$ is unflipped and $V(0,0,0,1)$ is the value where the card with value $4$ is unflipped.

I then work backwards. During my last turn, if the card that's unflipped is $1$ or $2$, I won't flip it. If it's $3$ or $4$, I will flip it. Then $V(1,0,0,0) = 9 + 2.5 = 11.5$, $V(0,1,0,0) = 10.5$, and $V(0,0,1,0) = V(0,0,0,1) = 10$.

It follows

$$V(1,1,0,0) = \max\left\{ \frac{1}{2} \left(V(1,0,0,0) + V(0,1,0,0)\right), 12\right\}$$

where the first argument in the max operator is the value of flipping and the second argument the value of not flipping.

I can back out $V(1,1,1,1)$ using this logic, until I realize I haven't proved that it's never optimal to stay input one round and then flip cards the next round.

Can I get a hint on this?

Comment: There are simpler ways to find the optimal strategy. Try considering the expected value at each step (working forwards) instead. The solution does not even really require that the player is risk-neutral. Can you see why there is no downside to flipping a card on the first turn?

Comment: Can you be more explicit? I can only discover that there's no downside through working backwards. One argument can be that flipping a card in the first turn has an expected value of 2.5, but that requires risk neutrality.

Comment: The point is that you can always achieve an average score of $2.5$ either by not flipping at all or by flipping all four.  Thus, there's an advantage to flipping initially...if you happen to flip the $1$ first, then you can just stop and thereby increase your total.  And if you happen to flip the $4$, well then you can just go ahead and flip all of them.

Comment: @lulu Can you write this as an answer? I can then select it. If I flip the 1 first, why would I stop? I would keep going since the expected value of flipping is larger than 2.5.

Comment: My comment is not a complete answer,  though it is close.  You have to analyze the cases more thoroughly.  Should you stop if you toss the $2$ initially or is it worth it to try for the $1$ next,  for instance.

Comment: Similarly,  if you toss the $3$ initially. You should consider the possible outcomes of the next trial.  As before,  there's no harm in going step by step. You can always guarantee the score of $10$ in the end.

Comment: @lulu See the dynamic programming solution below. The program stops whenever it draws the $4$ card. I can't come up with an analytical solution. Get I get a hint from you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148082/discussion-between-user1691278-and-lulu).

Comment: You can work this out case by case.  If you draw the $4$ first and the $1$ next then you have broken even.  If you next draw the $2$ then you are up $.5$ and should stop,  for a total score of $10.5$

Comment: To stress,  there is absolutely no need for a computer here.  There are only $4!=24$ possible sequences of draws, and you can just write all of them down and figure out the best move in each case.

Comment: @lulu Can I only do this by writing out all the 24 possible sequences?

Comment: Why would that be a challenge? In any case,  you really need to try something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ denote the set of cards (e.g., $U=\{1,2,3,4\}$).
Let $X$ denote the subset of cards that have been flipped. Let $v(t,X)$ be the value of playing the game with $t$ turns remaining.
Let $r$ be the reward for not flipping a card (e.g., $r=2.5$).
Trivially, $v(0,X)=0$ for any $X$.
Moreover, if $t>0$,
$$
v(t,X)=\max\left\{ \frac{1}{\left|U\setminus X\right|}\left(\sum_{x\in U\setminus X}v(t-1,X\cup\{x\})+x\right),v(t-1,X)+r\right\} .
$$

*Remark*. The above is understood w.r.t. the conventions $\sum_{x \in \emptyset} f(x) = 0$ and $0 / 0 = 0$.

This, with some simplifications, is implemented in the code below.

```
import functools
from typing import Tuple


def value(num_turns: int, no_flip_value: float, rewards: Tuple[float, ...]) -> float:
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def _value(mask: Tuple[bool, ...], num_turns_left: int) -> float:
        if num_turns_left == 0:
            return 0.0
        num_unflipped = sum(1 for mask_i in mask if not mask_i)
        stop_value = num_turns_left * no_flip_value
        if num_unflipped == 0:
            return stop_value
        mean_flip_value = (
            sum(
                rewards[i]
                + _value(
                    mask=mask[:i] + (True,) + mask[i + 1 :],
                    num_turns_left=num_turns_left - 1,
                )
                for i, mask_i in enumerate(mask)
                if not mask_i
            )
            / num_unflipped
        )
        return max(mean_flip_value, stop_value)

    return _value(mask=(False,) * len(rewards), num_turns_left=num_turns)


answer = value(num_turns=4, no_flip_value=2.5, rewards=(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0))
print(answer)
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining your reasoning? As of now, I cannot choose yours as an answer.

Comment: @user1691278: Done

Comment: Thank you. Is there an analytical solution? I noticed in your program, you stop flipping once you encounter the $4$ card.

Comment: @user1691278: I believe that's true. I think you can convince yourself by looking at in cases. There is certainly a closed form solution (for a reasonable definition of "closed form") since there is a finite number of cards.

Answer (score 2):

The state of the game can after any of the steps be noted as a set of face-values shown of the cards already flipped plus a letter N for each step where no card was flipped. Initially the state is empty. After step one the set of 5 states is {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {N}. After 2 steps the states are {1,2}, {1,3},.. {3,4}, {1,N}, {2,N},.. {N,N}, 6 with two numbers, 4 with one number and a N, and one with two N.  After 4 steps the states are {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,N},... {1,2,N,N}, ... {N,N,N,N}, one with 4 numbers, 4 with 3 numbers and a N, 6 with 2 numbers and 2 N, 4 with 1 number and three N, and one with 4 N.

These states can be organized in a poset (partially ordered set) where the initial state is at level 0, and each state at level i is linked to all states at level i+1 that may follow by either flipping or non-flipping. The value of the states at level 4 is the sum of the integers plus the number of N's times 2.5. The gambler tries to maximize the expectation value (EV) at each step.

If the gambler does not flip, the EV (I) would be the EV of the next state, defined by N added to the state; if the gambler flips, the EV (II) is 1/u times the sum of the expecation values of the next state by adding one of the yet non-flipped cards. [Here u is the number of cards not yet flipped.]
Example: if the state is {3} it's recommended to flip because the EV of {1,3} is 10.25, the EV of {2,3} is 10.75 and the EV of {3,4} is 12 (mean of these u=3 EV is 11) and the EV of {3,N} is 10.5, smaller.
The winning strategy is to assume that the EV of a state is the maximum of the two EV (I) and (II), which means the gambler decides to flip or not-to-flip branching with probability 1 or probability 1/u into a state of the next higher level.

This type of strategy and mathematics of probabilities is applicable to all kinds of multisets of cards with to-be-flipped face values and all values of (positive or negative) N-values.
The list of 48 states (each followed by a "f" to recommend to flip, a "n" to recommend not to flip, a "u" meaning flip or non-flip have the same EV, a "e" meaning end-of-the game, and the EV after the recommended action) is:

```
. f 10.8125  
1    f 10.166666666666666  
12   f 10.0  
123  f 10.0  
1234 e 10.0  
123N e 8.5  
124  f 10.0  
124N e 9.5  
12N  f 9.0  
12NN e 8.0  
13   f 10.25  
134  n 10.5  
134N e 10.5  
13N  f 9.5  
13NN e 9.0  
14   f 10.25  
14N  u 10.0  
14NN e 10.0  
1N   f 9.5  
1NN  f 9.0  
1NNN e 8.5  
2    f 10.583333333333334  
23   f 10.75  
234  n 11.5  
234N e 11.5  
23N  u 10.0  
23NN e 10.0  
24   n 11.0  
24N  n 11.0  
24NN e 11.0  
2N   f 10.0  
2NN  f 9.666666666666666  
2NNN e 9.5  
3    f 11.0  
34   n 12.0  
34N  n 12.0  
34NN e 12.0  
3N   u 10.5  
3NN  n 10.5  
3NNN e 10.5  
4    n 11.5  
4N   n 11.5  
4NN  n 11.5  
4NNN e 11.5  
N    f 10.375  
NN   f 10.166666666666666  
NNN  u 10.0  
NNNN e 10.0
```

So in summary the EV of the best strategy is 10.8125, and it's recommended to start with a flip, and to flip a second card if that first flip does not show the 4.

Comment: +1 I didn't read your answer in detail but also got 10.8125 from running the code in my answer.